# ¿Por qué no se implementa un proceso para aceptar respuestas de preguntas abandonadas?

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-rechazado

Varias veces me he encontrado en SO en inglés, y ahora ya empiezan a aparecer aquí, preguntas que tienen una buena respuesta pero que no está aceptada por un simple echo: El usuario que hizo la pregunta "***ha muerto***" (Vale, **no** ha muerto, pero ***ha desaparecido***).

La idea es sencilla. Si:

- El autor de la pregunta no se conecta en los últimos `X` días.
- Una de las respuestas tiene más de `Y` votos.
- No hay ninguna respuesta aceptada.

Si se cumplen todas esas condiciones se podría:

- Aceptar directamente la respuesta. (No lo haría así).
- Añadir una nueva cola de moderación para que requieras `Z` votos a favor para aceptar esa respuesta.

¿Cómo lo veis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Que una respuesta esté marcada como aceptada significa *que ha sido la más útil para el usuario que formuló la pregunta* , y es dicho usuario el único que puede decidir si eso es cierto o no. Añadir un mecanismo adicional como el sugerido crearía confusión, y te aseguro que más de un usuario que "no estaba muerto, estaba de parranda" volverá y no le sentará bien que alguien o algo haya aceptado una respuesta por él.

Sé que es frustrante trabajarse una buena respuesta para que luego la persona que preguntó pase de todo (a mí también me ha pasado), pero así es la vida... considerad los votos positivos como un premio de consolación. :-)

Por cierto, este tema [ya se discutió en Stack Overflow en el pasado](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262672/can-moderators-make-an-answer-accepted-to-close-the-post) con idéntico resultado.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la mayor parte excepto el que los votos positivos sean premio de consolación porque en ocasiones estos suman mas puntos de reputación que la aceptación de una respuesta. Justo se me vino a la mente que habiendo varias preguntas con un número alto de votos, se usara el mecanismo de recompensa para distinguir a una de la otra.

Comment: Quizá me expresé mal. Lo que quise decir es que en ausencia de aceptación, los votos positivos son igualmente una buena recompensa para el autor de la respuesta.