# Preguntas abandonadas, inclusive que tienen buenas respuestas y/o comentarios

Tags: discusión, preguntas, respuesta-aceptada

Mi estimada familia de SOes, tengo una sugerencia para ayudar a mejorar la salud de nuestra comunidad: **Enviar un correo electrónico** al usuario que ha formulado la pregunta.

Conforme he estado viendo las preguntas sin respuesta aceptada, veo que hay buenas respuestas y/o comentarios. Lamentablemente quien preguntó nunca más hizo caso a lo publicado.

¿Qué opinan de la sugerencia? Un correo diciendo algo así:

> Estimado usuario de StackOverflow En Español, hay actividad de la pregunta XYZ que ha formulado hace 1 mes, visite el siguiente enlace -> StackOverflow.com/url-pregunta para atender el contenido publicado.
>
> Un cordial saludo de vuestra comunidad hispana.

Comment: relacionado, http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287

Comment: La solución que siempre aplico es que cuando veo una así hago un comentario en favor del que dio la buena respuesta, así el usuario no parece que está rogando por reputación ya que yo no me beneficio, sin embargo ayudo a mantener el sitio saludable.

Comment: hago exactamente lo mismo, la idea es mantener el sitio saludable :D

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Por qué no se implementa un proceso para aceptar respuestas de preguntas abandonadas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/649/65)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La única manera de conocer el correo electrónico de un usuario es que el usuario lo comparta en la descripción de su perfil. Fuera de eso, solo los moderadores pueden visualizar el correo electrónico del usuario para casos de extrema urgencia, usualmente por problemas ocasionados en el sitio. Actualmente, si un moderador se comunica con un usuario por correo electrónico, lo hace mediante el sitio (no desde su correo personal) y ese aviso está sujeto a una sanción.

Espero que esto apoye un poco más a que no se puede notificar a un usuario por correo electrónico para que vuelva al sitio. Lo único que podemos hacer es dejar un comentario indicando que [acepte la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/227). Más que eso, no se puede.

Comment: El correo electrónico es un asunto privado a menos que el usuario decida lo contrario. Es bueno ver que Stack Overflow conoce esas reglas y respeta sus usuarios ;)

Comment: queda entonces, seguir haciendo comentarios :D