# Si tuvieras que mejorar un aspecto de SO-es, ¿cuál sería?¿Cómo lo mejorarías?

Tags: discusión

Varias de las preguntas que vengo viendo en Meta son sobre cuestiones tratar de mejorarse la Comunidad en un aspecto. Por ejemplo: [calidad de las preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/840/qu%c3%a9-deber%c3%adamos-hacer-a-las-preguntas-del-tipo-no-he-intentado-pero-quiero-resp), [puntuación de las preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/849/haz-1-a-las-preguntas-que-respondes), [abandono de preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/822/preguntas-abandonadas-inclusive-que-tienen-buenas-respuestas-y-o-comentarios), [mejora en las revisiones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/854/introducci%c3%b3n-de-los-review-audits)

Yo creo que con esas preguntas estamos viendo árboles y no el bosque, me parece que hay tratar entender el todo, que le pasa en la comunidad en general y que podemos hacer para mejorarla.

Si sólo pudieras elegir un sólo aspecto a mejorar, ¿cuál sería? ¿Cuál crees que sería la mejor manera de solucinarlo (como una vez me dijeron, si no traes soluciones a la mesa, eres parte del problema)? ¿Por qué es mejor atacar a ese problema y no otro (impacta directa o indirectamente sobre los otros, ataca un problema de raíz, es facilmente visible)?

Answer (score 13):

Para mi la parte más importante es la [puntuación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/849/7242) de las preguntas/respuestas junto al tamaño de la comunidad.

Ambas cosas van de la mano.

Creo que tenemos que votar mucho más para que haya más usuarios que obtengan privilegios y la comunidad se pueda gestionar con menos intervenciones constantes de nuestro moderador Luiggi.

Para dar un ejemplo; yo soy de españa y normalmente la actividad del sitio en nuestro horario de mañana es más baja y veo que hago [muchísimas gestiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7242/miquel-coll?tab=activity) o reportes que hasta varias *horas* más tarde no toman efecto ya que hay pocos usuarios activos con suficiente reputación en la comunidad.

Asimismo para que la comunidad crezca es necesario (desde mi punto de vista) intentar ayudar tanto como se pueda a los nuevos usuarios y ser generosos con los votos y [comentarios para ayudar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7242/miquel-coll?tab=activity&sort=comments).

- Un caso negativo:

  No es normal ver cómo [existen usuarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/10019/rf-mvs?tab=questions) que publican preguntas y no aceptan respuestas ni votan de manera positiva **nunca**. Esto es raro y des de mi punto de vista inaceptable para crear una buena comunidad.
- Otro caso negativo:

  La cola de revisión de [primeras publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history). Me encuentro muchos casos en los que se resuelve con `No se requiere ninguna acción`.

  [¿De verdad?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/22773/1) - Firmado con nombre, sin poner código como tal, sin poner mensaje de error como tal y el gracias (esto no es tan importante)

  [¿Seguro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/22849/1) - Este caso es muy bestia. El código era **muy necesario** marcarlo como tal, poner bien los puntos de 1, 2 y 3, el "a ver si hay suerte" y "saludos" (opcional).

  [¿No hacía falta **nada**?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/22707/1) - Creo que no hace falta ni comentarlo. Se han hecho ya 5 ediciones y aún no está bien al 100%.

  Y eso son 3 ejemplos cualquiera de esa cola que des de mi punto de vista *requerían* algún tipo de acción. Entre ellos, considero esta cola de revisión **muy** importante para dar ese primer voto positivo a un nuevo usuario (si la pregunta/respuesta) se lo merece.

  Precisamente por estos casos (y muchísimos similares) he propuesto introducir los [review audits](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/854/7242) para evitar que simplemente se revisen las colas para las medallas y ya está.
- Un caso *curioso*:

  [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20804/7242) que realicé en su día tiene 1 único voto positivo. Si miramos su publicación original tiene 5542 votos positivos (como mínimo). ¿Por qué este tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas aquí?
- Otro caso:

  [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22925/7242) estaba aceptada y con un comentario de gracias y *0 votos*. Yo fui el primero en darle +1. ¿Cómo puede ser?

Creo que somos demasiado quisquillosos con los votos positivos. Creo que tendríamos que tener como objetivo conseguir lo antes posible la medalla [Sufragio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/suffrage) y votar tanto como nos sea posible cada día (repito: *sólo* si la pregunta/respuesta se lo merece). Veo *tantas* preguntas y respuestas en las que el único voto positivo es *mío* que empiezo a preguntarme si soy *yo* el que lo hace mal (y parece eso).

Comment: Por motivos como los que expones es que era prácticamente imposible lograr los objetivos del segundo concurso.  Totalmente de acuerdo salvo por la publicidad de tu pregunta ;) podrías haberla convertido en wiki (solo mi opinión).

Comment: Sobre lo de wiki leí en su día aquí en [meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/74/7242) que éramos libres en ese sentido =P Y no lo hago por la publicidad, de verdad. Pero es el único caso que conozco de este tipo, si tienes otro lo cambio con gusto! Y sí, era imposible el segundo concurso de esta manera...

Comment: @Shaz juro que ha sido por casualidad que he añadido una respuesta tuya. Me acabo de dar cuenta.

Comment: Normalmente le doy +1 a lo que respondo y a lo que veo en 0 y ya tiene respuesta aceptada (así sean preguntas de temas que no conozca). Estoy de acuerdo con lo que dices.

Comment: Me acabo de gastar mis 30 votos en nada. La verdad es que hay un montón de buenas preguntas.

Comment: @ElAsiduo ¡felicidades por la medalla [Sufragio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/suffrage)! Yo intento votar bastante, ya llevo unas cuantas veces con el máximo diario :)

Comment: @MiquelColl Me la gané el finde ;-P

Comment: Buenos días. ¿Te has fijado las características que se piden de un ejemplo en esta comunidad? Mínimo, completo y reproducible. Pones tres ejemplos (en dos tu eres el protagonista) que son mínimos, completos pero **son eventos únicos**. Seguramente con recursos suficientes tal vez encuentres mas, pero ¿a que costo?

Comment: @toledano no sé a qué te refieres con protagonista. No importa si son eventos únicos o no. Si deben ser cerrados, no es "No se requiere ninguna acción".

Comment: Mas tarde contesto, con la amplitud que la pregunta merece, porque es importante si son eventos únicos.

Comment: hazme un ping en el chat cuándo contestes porfa :)

Comment: Respecto de la pregunta traducida con 5k votos en inglés. Ten encuenta que hay [usuarios poco favorables](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/66/301) a [que se traduzcan](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/65/301) [preguntas famosas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-de-preguntas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl%c3%a9s#comment415_93) de SOen a SOes. Llegan incluso a poner votos negativos a esas preguntas.

Comment: He traducido esa pregunta porqué me encontré con ese problema y decidí compartirlo con la comunidad. En lugar de apropiarme de la pregunta/respuesta vi que en So ya había esa pregunta/respuesta y decidí traducirlo... Yo creo que entra dentro de la definición que se definió en ese post =P

Comment: Me parece que hay muchas formas de votar, no todo el mundo vota con el mismo criterio. Bajar ese criterio y votar mas -como una medida economica- deprecia el valor del voto, las medallas, etc. Fomenta la desigualdad entre los nuevos y los experimentados y hace mas elitista al sitio. Al contrario, hay que subir el standard del voto, para empujar a la comunidad a dar mejores preguntas/respuestas.

Comment: Otro usuario de aquellos: http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4456/omar-alami

Comment: @Shaz este usuario claramente no sabe que puede marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Va, al menos entiendo eso al ver que no marcó ninguna.

Comment: En cuanto a la cola de "Primeras publicaciones" me he equivocado en varias y ahora me doy cuenta de que podría haber hecho mejor en algunas revisiones. Gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Cuando se formulen preguntas, que haya una plantilla que sugiera el siguiente contenido:

- Paso 0: Comenta tu escenario.
- Paso 1: Escribe tu código, seleccionalo y presiona en el boton: { } así tendras un bonito formato.
- Paso 2: Copia y pega el error. Para darle mejor formato coloca el signo ">" delante del error.
- Paso 3: Qué otras alternativas has intentado?

Comment: Sería genial que esto se le presente a nuevos usuarios. Lo que sí, me parece que "plantilla" es un poco fuerte, ya que no todas las preguntas tienen que seguir este formato (ej: preguntas de buena calidad sin código).

Answer (score 4):

Para mí, más importante que la reputación en sí, es la educación que podemos dar a los usuarios nuevos sobre el uso de la plataforma. Al brindar una buena educación de nuestro lado, podemos ayudar a que sus publicaciones a futuro sean de mejor calidad, voten a favor/en contra, voten a cierre como corresponda, brinden comentarios que ayuden a mejorar el sitio, inclusive a que participen en Meta y provean más aporte al sitio. Y luego, como consecuencia, que ellos también eduquen a nuevos usuarios y este ciclo siga y luego se pueda llegar a un proceso de mejora continua (ok, sueño mucho, pero siempre aspiro alto porque soñar no cuesta nada).

Es cierto, no todos los usuarios nuevos van a aceptar esto. Es más, no tengo estadísticas de cuántos usuarios nuevos son los que continúan participando en el sitio. Pero al menos veo los efectos de eso poco a poco cuando me paseo en la sala de chat y en el sitio y veo que un mismo usuario va publicando más preguntas, están activos y van ganando reputación. Eso es buen síntoma.

Para ello, lo que me preocupa mucho es que hay usuarios que votan a cerrar una pregunta y no colocan ningún comentario para educar a los usuarios. Muchos creemos (lo digo porque he estado en ese lugar en SO) que los usuarios van a entrar a los enlaces a ver qué sucede. Lo que en realidad sucede (y lo he visto con compañeros de trabajo que han publicado preguntas y les han sido cerradas) es que **la gente ve su pregunta cerrada** (decir que está en espera lo toman como cerrado, sin importar la redacción) se desanima, no encuentra razón y abandona el sitio. Otras personas (muchas menos) revisan los enlaces de ayuda pero no encuentran una guía de cómo preguntar mejor, así que cometen el mismo error y su pregunta le es cerrada nuevamente. Así sucede unas 3 o 4 veces (según he visto aquí) hasta que el usuario simplemente se cansa y abandona el sitio.

Los comentarios **ayudan bastante, más de lo que te imaginas**. Asimismo, **colocar un comentario no cuesta nada**. Yo recomendaría a las personas que si piensan que una pregunta se debe cerrar, coloquen un comentario para ayudar a la persona a que revise mejor lo que sucede. Da ese grano de arena adicional.

Comment: [relacionado](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/796/7242). Creo que Estamos mejorando en ese sentido y estoy de acuerdo con lo que dices.

Comment: @MiquelColl lastimosamente sigo viendo esos casos. Se genera un reporte automático de estos casos para los moderadores.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. No se puede esperar que un recién llegado (la mayoría no ha leído el "manual de uso" de SOes) entienda que una pregunta cerrada no es un rechazo. SOes es un sitio en que las preguntas se pretende que sean útiles para la posteridad, no solo para quien pregunta. Dado que SOes se maneja en un marco temporal tan largo no tiene ningún sentido el apresuramiento con el cierre de preguntas.

Comment: Creo que habría que saber cual es la proporción de reincidencia al sitio y tratar de ver qué ha hecho que esas  ¡personas reincidan. Yo estoy porque Bender me dijo que hay blackjack y las m... :-P (ahh! No hay de eso por acá.. bueno me quedo contestando si puedo)

Comment: @MiquelColl [aquí un claro ejemplo de que este es un grave problema](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/23474/227).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Deberíamos ayudar a los otros a mejorar sus preguntas y respuestas, porque eso nos hace hacer mejores preguntas y respuestas. Ayudar debería primar por sobre las formas.

**Versión larga**

Antes que nada, gracias por su respuestas, al menos en mi caso me hace examinar cómo estoy participando de SOes (y si no soy parte del problema).

Me topé en la semana con estos artículos:

- [Why Stackoverflow sucks](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/)
- [The decline of Stackoverflow](https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.z6jqz3axo)
- [Are high-reputation users quitting Stack Overflow?](http://varianceexplained.org/r/are_users_quitting/)

En el segundo artículo me topé con esto:

> However, a 2013 study has found that [77% of users only ask one question, 65%  only answer one question, and only 8% of users answer more than 5 questions](http://www.webcitation.org/6NeNOY5oR)

UPA! Esos números a mí me sorprendieron.

Luego al igual del primer artículo habla de cómo se suele tratar a los recién llegados o a aquellos que hacen preguntas que no se adecuan según algunos personajes a SO.

Habría que ver como esa información se traslada a SOes.

De todas formas creo que hace reflexionar sobre algunas de las cosas que plantearon.

No sé si la palabra es educar, porque me hace pensar en esto de que nos vamos a comportar como fanáticos (el fanatismo en ningún ámbito para mí es bueno), me suena a *yo sé como se hacen las cosas bien y vos no*.

Creo que ayudar para mí capta el espíritu de SO (al menos lo creo yo era es el espíritu), que es que alguien tiene un problema, lo podamos ayudar a resolverlo.

OJO! Presumo que ese no fue el espíritu de la respuesta de Luiggi, sólo aclaro que mucha gente confunde muy fácilmente educar con instruir. Educar tiene retroalimentación, ambos educador y educando aprenden la experiencia.

Muy posiblemente, la gente en general venga y pregunte una vez y ya. Que vuelvan y haga crecer a la comunidad, creo que tiene que con contestarle la pregunta en tiempo (según el que pregunta) y de como los tratemos.

Entiendo que eso sólo puede venir de cada uno de nosotros, pero que no puede ser un esfuerzo individual, si no colectivo.

El último artículo habla que por mucho entusiasmo que le pongamos al asunto en un momento dado, eventualmente dejaremos a otros la luz de los reflectores. Es decir, eventualmente le daremos más participación a otros, espero que los trolls no se adueñen de esta comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Sin duda el tema de la puntuación es algo importante, ya que con ello, gente que esta respondiendo bien a las preguntas, se les puede otorgar mas privilegios.

Quizá sería bueno que en algún privilegio, se pudiese marcar una respuesta como aceptada, al igual que ocurre para votar, de esta manera creo que tendría mas sentir SO

Comment: [relacionado](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/649/7242) Ya se ha hablado y rechazado muchas veces =P

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Mejoraría los parámetros de [Área 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish), con tres acciones: a) aumentando mi radio de preguntas aceptadas, b) aumentando los votos que recibo en la etiqueta [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (para empezar) y c) Haciendo comentarios que aporten valor.

---

Yo hoy voy a hablar de un principio y un conjunto de herramientas que nos permitirán contestar esas preguntas. Me gustaría aclarar la diferencia entre **principio** y *regla*. Una regla es algo estricto y que debe obedecerse sin desviación (*debes votar siempre*), un principio es algo más flexible y no requiere de una obediencia tan rígida (*vota frecuentemente, vota lo más pronto posible*).

Con esta diferenciación me gustaría presentarles un principio de administración de procesos que en inglés se llama *factual aproach* 
y que en español recibe el pomposo nombre de

### Enfoque basado en hechos para la toma de decisiones

Este principio se expresa como sigue:

> Las decisiones efectivas se basan en el análisis de datos e información.

Los colectivos que aplican este principio se caracterizan porque las personas:

- Definen medidas de desempeño que describen las características de calidad para los procesos que miden
- Toman mediciones y recolectan datos e información relacionada con estos procesos
- Se aseguran que los datos y la información son suficientemente exacta, confiable y accesible
- Analizan la información usando métodos válidos
- Comprenden el valor de usar técnicas estadísticas válidas
- Toman acciones y decisiones basados en los resultados de un análisis lógico, con un adecuado balance que incluye la experiencia y la intuición.

Decía en [otra respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/855/638) que una mejora debe ser *medible*, *oportuna*, *efectiva* y *económica*. Recomiendo que las acciones que se tomen deben iniciar con la primera persona del singular, tipo *"Yo voy a contestar tres preguntas diarias sobre el tema que domino que se encuentran en la sección de **No contestadas**"*.

¿Cómo podemos saber, tomando en cuenta el principio de toma de decisiones basadas en datos, qué mejoras debo aplicar, buscando que sean medibles, oportunas, efectivas y económicas? Usando técnicas estadísticas.

Hay una muy impactante que se llama:

#### Principio de Pareto

Este principio dice más o menos así (vean la [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_Pareto))

> El 80% de los problemas se resuelve eliminado el 20% de las causas.

Y usando un [Diagrama de Pareto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagrama_de_Pareto) podemos definir las prioridades. Es decir, decidir que *causa* tiene mayor impacto y atacarlo con más recursos.

Seguramente conocen este diagrama:

[image: Diagrama de Pareto]

Una vez explicados estos conceptos, paso a mi propuesta.

> ¿Qué pensaron que iba a hacer un diagrama de Pareto con problemas y porcentaje de impacto? No, paso directo a los números.

## Propuesta

> Debemos dedicar nuestros esfuerzos a aquello que tenga mayor impacto en el logro de nuestro objetivo.

Este es un principio básico de gestión que nos permite concentrar nuestros esfuerzos en aquello que es mas redituable.

Pero, **¿cuál es nuestro objetivo?**. No lo sé a ciencia cierta, pero supongo que está relacionado con la propuesta del [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) y es dejar el estatus de Beta y ser un sitio con todos los derechos y obligaciones dentro de la comunidad de Stack Exchange. *(Supongo que estar en beta implica un riesgo que el experimento se cancele)*.

> Propuesta para un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores entusiastas y profesionales en Español.

De los 5 indicadores que existen, dos de ellos tienen oportunidades de mejora:

- Porcentaje de preguntas con respuesta. **Actual: 73%** - *Objetivo: 90%*
- Radio Preguntas:Respuestas. **Actual: 1.9** - *Objetivo: 2.5*

Esas son las dos cosas que propongo mejorar.

## Cómo mejorar esos indicadores:

1. **Aumenta tu radio de preguntas aceptadas**. El mío está en 38%, tengo que mejorar mis respuestas (aumento por calidad) o contestar mas preguntas (aumento por volumen). [¿Cuál es tu radio de preguntas aceptadas?](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/949/what-is-my-accepted-answer-percentage-rate#resultSets).
2. **Aumenta el número de votos por etiqueta**. Tengo 33 votos [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) y 22 en [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). ¿Lo mejor? ¡Dan medallas! Voy por la de Python. [¿Cuál es tu etiqueta más votada?](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag).
3. **Haz comentarios que aporten valor, que reciban votos**. Tengo 166 que no llamaron la atención, pero 53 que recibieron por lo menos un voto, debo hacer mejores comentarios. [¿Cuántos votos tienen tus comentarios?](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution).

En general, soy de la idea que antes de esperar a que otras personas cambien de actitud (esperando que otros sean agradecidos y nos regalen un voto, esperando que otros revisen las primeras publicaciones correctamente, esperando que otros escriban o editen correctamente una pregunta a la primera, etc.), debemos cambiar nosotros primero. La acción que genera el cambio, empieza con el (dijera Sabina) *"el capullo de detrás del espejo"*.

Pero, hay algunas cosas que es importante promover comunidad. La mas importante es votar frecuentemente y lo más pronto posible. *Flipo* con esta estadística "Usuarios con muchos votos pero que casi nunca votan": http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/6856/high-standards-top-100-users-that-rarely-upvote

El sitio de las estadísticas es este: http://data.stackexchange.com/es/queries

Y tiene un tutorial: http://data.stackexchange.com/help#introduction

Comment: Tu radio de preguntas aceptadas no necesariamente aumentará por alguna de esas acciones. Aumentar la cantidad de respuestas, incluso puede disminuirlo.

Comment: Y sobre los otros dos puntos no me queda claro, cuál es el racional. Salvo que venga de la mano de lo que menciona @Mariano

Answer (score 0):

**Limitar la posibilidad de nuevas preguntas, mientras se tengan preguntas antiguas abiertas y contestadas, y ni se han molestado en aceptarlas o votar a favor o en contra.**

Ayer mismo contesté una pregunta a un usuario, y hoy me encuentro una nueva pregunta del mismo usuario, utilizando todo el código de mi respuesta en su anterior pregunta sin ni siquiera molestarse en votar a favor, en contra o aceptar dicha respuesta.

Resulta algo frustrante, y lo digo yo que llevo muy poco tiempo en la comunidad, que después de molestarse en responder, empleando para ello os o tres horas programando y comentando el código para que sea entendido, y luego el que pregunte, use ese código para formalizar una nueva pregunta y ni se digne en votar la primera.

Creo que no estaría mal, que si un usuario tiene una pregunta abierta con respuestas, al intentar realizar una nueva pregunta, le salga un recordatorio de sus preguntas abiertas y respondidas y de que tiene que efectuar una acción sobre las mismas, bien sea votando a favor, en contra, o aceptando la respuesta, o de lo contrario, no se le permita efectuar la nueva pregunta.

Comment: Y le dejaste un comentario diciendole eso? le enseñaste a usar el sitio? obviamente quiero creer que su nueva pregunta no la contestaste hasta tener un feedback de la anterior, no?

Comment: Le hice un comentario de que tenía respondida la anterior y aún abierta y que le recomendaba aceptar mi respuesta, pues había pegado todo mi código en la actual pregunta. Como no hizo ningún movimiento, insistí con otro comentario en el que le decía que no contestaría una nueva pregunta sin interactura en la anterior pregunta abierta y que evidentemente estan relacionadas, pues el código íntegro de la respuesta anterior con el código nuevo añadido es la base de la nueva pregunta..

Comment: Pongo los accesos a las preguntas en otro comentario, pues no cabía en el anterior. [1ª pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/464874/c%c3%b3mo-retorno-un-valor-next-de-una-funcion-para-usarlo-en-otra).[2ª Pregunt](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465021/c%c3%b3mo-se-retorna-una-funci%c3%b3n-correctamente)

Comment: el usuario tiene 2 preguntas.. nadie, pero nadie, le indico que hiciera el tour para saber por lo menos las bases de como funciona el sitio. Los usuarios no recorren nada, a menos que los llevemos de la mano....

Comment: Si @gbianchi, tienes razón a lo que respecta a éste caso en concreto, pero yo con mi propuesta de mejora, aunque basada en ésta experiencia, era generalizando, pues tengo visto en varias ocasiones lo mismo, gente que realiza una pregunta, le contestan, y sin interactuar con la respuesta, formula una nueva pregunta dejando la anterior abierta. De ahí que sugería, que si cabía la posibilidad de dar un aviso a la gente que haya formulado su pregunta y haya sido respondido, que sin interactuar con la respuesta, sea votando a favor o en contra o aceptando la respuesta, no pueda preguntar de nuevo.

Answer (score -1):

Me doy cuenta de que hay mucha gente que escribe mal en castellano, y pienso que sería una buena idea para ayudar al que pregunta y al que lee la pregunta, hacer que cosas obvias de ortografía el sistema pudiera avisar de que está mal escrito. Hay cosas obvias como que en castellano todas las preguntas empiezan por (¿) si terminan por (?) y que la palabra (cómo) cuando es pregunta va con acento. Y otras tantas cosas que si el sistema pudiera detectar los errores el que escribe podría escribir mejor.

Aunque aprobar ediciones también recoloca tu pregunta en las primeras posiciones cuando ha bajado mucho es interesante.

Answer (score -1):

## Agregar la posibilidad de indicar cuándo una respuesta no responde la pregunta

Ya me pasó en SO en inglés y una vez me pasó en SO es español (en [Cómo interceptar toda la salida de express en una aplicación nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23457/c%C3%B3mo-interceptar-toda-la-salida-de-express-en-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-nodejs))

Hago una pregunta, alguien contesta enseguida con una respuesta que no contesta la pregunta. Eso hace que la pregunta pierda interés (algunos que podrían contestar ven que ya tiene respuesta y buscan contestar otra).

Alguna vez me pasó a mí de publicar una respuesta que no contestaba la pregunta. Cuando me lo hicieron ver la retiré. Pero no todos los usuarios lo hacen.

## Propuesta:

1. Que exista un botón (cerca del tilde) que permita indicar "he leído en profundidad esta respuesta y no contesta la pregunta qué he formulado ni ayuda a obtener una solución".
2. Que esas respuestas queden marcadas y sean restadas del número de respuestas que se muestran en la lista de preguntas (o que aparezcan con un número más chiquito)