# ¿Qué sucede con las preguntas que tienen respuestas validas pero no son marcadas como aceptadas?

Tags: soporte, respuesta-aceptada

Sucede en algunos casos (principalmente en preguntas formuladas por usuarios que no están familiarizados con la familia de *stack exchange*), que se formulan preguntas. Después reciben una o varias respuestas validas pero el usuario no marca ninguna como aceptada.

¿Qué sucede con esas preguntas? ¿El sistemas la relega en las búsquedas por no tener respuesta aceptada y las considera de menor importancia? ¿La comunidad puede marcarla como aceptada? ¿Los administradores pueden marcar alguna respuesta como aceptada a pesar de no ser una pregunta formulada por ellos?

Sobre todo porque algunas veces se les invita a los usuarios a marcar una respuesta como aceptada pero aún así no lo hacen.

Comment: @x4mp73r mi pregunta está enfocada a saber que sucede con esas preguntas, el posible duplicado que mencionas se refiere a como inducir al usuario a que marque las respuestas como aceptadas. No creo que sea un duplicado

Comment: Ok, he retirado el voto, error mío. Pero mas bien parece un duplicado de esta http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/822/preguntas-abandonadas-inclusive-que-tienen-buenas-respuestas-y-o-comentarios

Comment: Voto por reabrirla, principalmente por **uno** de los puntos tratados: como se manejan las búsquedas de los usuarios y si afecta el hecho de que una pregunta esté o no *aceptada*; curiosidad profesional, podriamos decir.

Comment: Sí. como ya había dicho: las supuestas preguntas  duplicadas se refieren a como inducir al usuario a que marque las respuestas como aceptadas. Mi pregunta es en relación a qué hace el sistemas con esas preguntas sin aceptar

Comment: @ReneLimon ¿puede esta pregunta estar relacionada? http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/287/6635 o bien podría responder **¿La comunidad puede marcarla como aceptada?**  y **¿Los administradores pueden marcar alguna respuesta como aceptada a pesar de no ser una pregunta formulada por ellos?**

Comment: @JuankGlezz esa fue la primera pregunta sugerida como duplicada, pero siento que eso esta enfocado a la forma de orientar al usuario nuevo a cómo utilizar el sitio. Yo quiero saber que hace el sistema con las preguntas, es una respuesta parcial a mi pregunta

Comment: El sistema no hace nada. El único que tiene el poder de aceptar una respuesta es quien creó la pregunta. Si no la acepta, no pasa nada en el sistema.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Me parece que tu comentario debería ser publicado como respuesta y que se podría incluir como referencia este FAQ: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

## Respuesta corta

Desde la perspectiva de graduación del sitio, no es importante que las preguntas tengan una respuesta aceptada, lo importante es que tengan respuestas con votos positivos. Referencia: [Respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1279/65) a [¿Cómo funciona la estadística "porcentaje de preguntas contestadas" en Area 51?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/985/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-estad%C3%ADstica-porcentaje-de-preguntas-contestadas-en-area-51)

Véase: [PROPUESTA: Usemos el botón y pestaña Sin Responder](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457/)

## Respuestas puntuales

> ¿Qué sucede con esas preguntas?

La plataforma de Stack Exchange cuenta con un algoritmo para "reflotar" estas preguntas. Se muestran como actualizadas por el usuario [Community](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad).

En Meta SE, las [preguntas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-user+bump?sort=votes&pageSize=15) con [community-user] y [bump] tratan el tema.

> ¿El sistemas la relega en las búsquedas por no tener respuesta aceptada y las considera de menor importancia?

No.

> ¿La comunidad puede marcarla como aceptada?

No.

> ¿Los administradores pueden marcar alguna respuesta como aceptada a pesar de no ser una pregunta formulada por ellos?

No.

## Relacionadas

- [Respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/650/65) a [¿Por qué no se implementa un proceso para aceptar respuestas de preguntas abandonadas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/649/)

Comment: Gracias, tenìa la duda y es que aveces respondo preguntas y apesar que tienen positivos, veo que el usuario que realiza la pregunta no la marca como aceptada entonces yo siento como si no le interesa.

Comment: @OscarDavidDiazFortaleché Lamentablemente algunos autores hacen la pregunta y nunca vuelven, olvidan marcar como aceptada alguna respuesta o no les interesa, pero no te preocupes tanto por eso. Quizás sea más relevante ver el número de vistas que tiene el hilo y el número de usuarios a los que impactas (esto último lo ves en tu perfil)